# Dutch 5-year MVV in country of origin passport valid for 3 months

Tags: visas, netherlands, long-stay-visas, schengen-visas

Last year I have received Dutch 5-year MVV visa, came to the Netherlands and received my residence permit valid till year 2021. However, recently I checked my original country's passport and noticed that the *until* date is stated to be October, 2016 (whereas my Dutch residence permit is valid until August, 2021). I have 2 questions:

1. Does it mean that I am living illegally in the Netherlands?
2. If I leave EU, does it mean that I will not be able to come back, given that I do not have any other Schengen visas?

Comment: OP, the title doesn't match the text. Is the October _2016_ date correct? That is, your passport has expired? Or does it expire in October _2017_?

Comment: @mkennedy I believe that the MVV has expired in October 2016 ("does it mean that I *am* living illegally in the Netherlands," present tense).  The reason for "checked the passport" is that the MVV is inserted there in the form of a type-D national visa sticker.

Comment: Oh, I see. The visa stamp in the passport was until 10/2016 while the residence permit is until 2021. Thanks, @phoog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first question belongs on [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com), but the second question is arguably on topic here, so I will answer that in a way that also addresses the first question.

The answer is that your residence permit *replaces* the MVV (which is why the MVV is valid for such a short time; the Dutch *machtiging tot voorlopig verblijf* means "authorization for temporary stay").  It is not clear why you believe it to be a "five-year" MVV.

The [Schengen Borders Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0399-20170407) notes explicitly in Article 6, paragraph (1)(b), an exception to the requirement to hold a visa (emphasis added):

> they are in possession of a valid visa, if required pursuant to Council Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 ( 5 ), **except where they hold a valid residence permit** or a valid long-stay visa;

So, as long as your residence permit is valid, you do not need a Schengen visa, you can travel in and out of the Schengen area, and you are not living illegally in the Netherlands.